# Can I change my Redux state from outside a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm storing my api access token in Redux state. When my access token expires my api sends back a refreshed token as a header. What I'm trying to do is set up an axios interceptor that will change my state if a refreshed token is sent back.

```
const myAxios = axios.create()

myAxios.interceptors.response.use(
(response) => {
if (response.headers['x-access-token']) {
  // Is there a way to dispatch something here to change state
}

return response
},
async function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

export default myAxios
```

So with this I can get my token fine I just cant figure out how to change state from here
since useDispatch wont work from outside a functional component

Comment: export the redux store, then import it in your file `import { store } from './store'` and use it like: `store.dispatch()`

Comment: If possible, consider storing it in a cookie or local storage instead and read it from there when you need it. That will save you from issues when users work with multiple tabs.

Comment: The access token, which is only required by your axios instance, doesn't necessarily need to reside in the redux store. You can keep it in a let variable in your api client module and expose a setter function so store it. It is technically not even "global application state" (the purpose of redux) and not required in multiple react components. Global application state would be "is the user logged in?".

Comment: @TorreyHowell, I have posted the solution as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73598664/14886355)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, export your store:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  ...
});
```

Then, import it in your file and use it:

```
import { store } from './store';

...
store.dispatch() // got dispatch
```

Comment: **We _strongly discourage_ directly importing the store into other files!**  This is likely to cause circular import issues. _If_ you need to access the store in other files, inject it from the entry point file instead: https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files